# Start JBoss 7 as a service on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, jboss7.x, start-stop-daemon

Previous versions of JBoss included a scripts (like `jboss_init_redhat.sh`) that could be copied to /etc/init.d in order to add it as a service - so it would start on boot up. I can't seem to find any similar scripts in JBoss 7. Has anyone already done something like this?

P.S.
I'm trying to achieve this in Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 59, accepted):

After spending a couple of hours of snooping around I ended up creating `/etc/init.d/jboss` with the following contents

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          jboss
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/Stop JBoss AS v7.0.0
### END INIT INFO
#
#source some script files in order to set and export environmental variables
#as well as add the appropriate executables to $PATH
[ -r /etc/profile.d/java.sh ] && . /etc/profile.d/java.sh
[ -r /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh ] && . /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting JBoss AS 7.0.0"
        #original:
        #sudo -u jboss sh ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh

        #updated:
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --chuid jboss --exec ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh
    ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping JBoss AS 7.0.0"
        #original:
        #sudo -u jboss sh ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-admin.sh --connect command=:shutdown

        #updated:
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --chuid jboss --exec ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-admin.sh -- --connect command=:shutdown
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/jboss {start|stop}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Here's the content of `java.sh`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java_current
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And `jboss.sh`:

```
export JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/as/jboss_current
export PATH=$JBOSS_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Obviously, you need to make sure, you set JAVA_HOME and JBOSS_HOME appropriate to your environment.

then I ran `sudo update-rc.d jboss defaults` so that JBoss automatically starts on system boot

I found [this article](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) to be helpful in creating the start-up script above. Again, the script above is for Ubuntu (version 10.04 in my case), so using it in Fedora/RedHat or CentOS will probably not work (the setup done in the comments is different for those).

Comment: See also [chkconfig](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/chkconfig.8.html), `--add` option.

Comment: You can use such construction to import `jboss.sh` file: `[ -r /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh ] && source /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh`

Comment: Why are the lines `[ -r /etc/profile.d/java.sh ] && . /etc/profile.d/java.sh` and `[ -r /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh ] && . /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh` necessary?

Comment: @Kawu: the explanation is right above the two lines... i'm sourcing the contents of those two files in order to set the appropriate environmental variables (JBOSS_HOME, JAVA_HOME, PATH)

Comment: You mean the answer to my question would rather have been that environment vars aren't exported at boot time (which isn't obvious for everybody)

Comment: @Kawu: do let me know how to export the environment variables at boot prior to the init.d scripts running... I've been wondering how I could achieve this properly

Comment: @Andrey: Can you please provide an example of `jboss.sh` and `java.sh`? Then your solutions will be complete and no one is wondering if he missed something in these files.

Comment: @Thor: no problem, I updated my answer. I'm also planning on updating the instructions to use the start-stop-daemon (since that's the proper way to start/stop services)

Comment: Add lines "# chkconfig: 2345 64 36" and "# description: Jboss Start|Restart|Stop Application Server" after "END INIT INFO" to add support for CentOS/RedHat chkconfig.

Comment: The `--user` option of the `start-stop-daemon` is used for matching a process to stop, not to start process as a specific user. To change user, use `--chuid jboss`.

Comment: @mrzasa i changed it to --chuid. i think what happened was i look at http://linuxreviews.org/man/start-stop-daemon and according to that one, --chuid is the same as --user. but double checking on the actual system via "man stop-start-daemon" agrees with what you say...

Comment: On JBoss AS 7.1.1 **jboss-admin.sh** script does not exist. Instead you may use **jboss-cli.sh**

Comment: The problem with that script is that it does not wait for the server to be really started before returning. [Mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15222719/535203) takes care of that (and permits the restart, checks if the user exists, etc etc...)

Comment: @AnthonyO. i was always under the impression that blocking in the boot up scripts was not a good idea...

Answer (score 12):

I also took a shot at a script for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. JBoss version is 7.1.1. I wanted a script that really tests for successful JBoss startup and that is able to shut down JBoss relatively gracefully. My starting point was the JBoss script included in the bin/init.d directory in the JBoss 7.1.1 download. I adapted this with some bits from other scripts on this page as well as other Ubuntu init scripts. Note that Ubuntu uses dash as its default init-script interpreter, not bash as apparently expected by the JBoss script.
Of medium importance is that the logging takes place in `/var/log/jboss-as` instead of `${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/log`. The log is also used to determine if JBoss started up successfully.

`jboss-as-standalone.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# JBoss standalone control script
#
# Provided in JBoss AS 7.1.1
# Modified for Ubuntu Server 10.04 by koma
#
# chkconfig: - 80 20
# description: JBoss AS Standalone
# processname: standalone
# pidfile: /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid
# config: /etc/default/jboss-as
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          jboss-as
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Should-Start:      $named
# Should-Stop:       $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start JBoss AS
# Description:       Start JBoss Application Server.
### END INIT INFO
#

# Inspired by tomcat6 init script, might be somewhat redundant
#PATH=???
NAME=jboss-as
DESC="JBoss AS"
DEFAULT=/etc/default/$NAME

# Source function library.
#. /etc/init.d/functions
# Ubuntu has it here (but probably different !)
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Load Java configuration.
# Ubuntu has it in /etc/default
[ -r /etc/default/java ] && . /etc/default/java
export JAVA_HOME

# Load JBoss AS init.d configuration.
if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONF" ]; then
# Ubuntu: seems more logical there
  JBOSS_CONF="/etc/default/jboss-as"
fi

[ -r "$JBOSS_CONF" ] && . "${JBOSS_CONF}"

# Set defaults.

if [ -z "$JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
  JBOSS_HOME="/var/local/jboss-as"
fi
export JBOSS_HOME

# might be unbeautiful
# this made chown fail because JBOSS_USER was empty
if [ -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
  JBOSS_USER="jboss"
fi
export JBOSS_USER

if [ -z "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" ]; then
  JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid
fi
export JBOSS_PIDFILE

#if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG" ]; then
#  JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG=/var/log/jboss-as/console.log
#fi
# use JBOSS_LOG_DIR from jboss script instead
if [ -z "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR" ]; then
  JBOSS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/jboss-as
fi
export JBOSS_LOG_DIR

# We need this to be set to get a pidfile !
if [ -z "$LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND" ]; then
  LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=true
fi
export LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND

if [ -z "$STARTUP_WAIT" ]; then
  STARTUP_WAIT=120
fi

if [ -z "$SHUTDOWN_WAIT" ]; then
  SHUTDOWN_WAIT=120
fi

if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONFIG" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONFIG=standalone.xml
fi

JBOSS_SCRIPT=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh

prog='jboss-as'


start() {
  log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC"
  id $JBOSS_USER > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ $? -ne 0 -o -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
    log_failure_msg "User $JBOSS_USER does not exist..."
    log_end_msg 1
    exit 1
  fi
  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read ppid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
      log_progress_msg "$prog is already running"
      log_end_msg 0
      exit 0
    else
      rm -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    fi
  fi
  mkdir -p $JBOSS_LOG_DIR
  # not sure: clear boot.log ... dunno if good, dunno if hardcoding boot.log good
  cat /dev/null > ${JBOSS_LOG_DIR}"/boot.log"
  # same as for boot.log, but we need to clear server.log to get proper launch detection (grepping later)
  cat /dev/null > ${JBOSS_LOG_DIR}"/server.log"
  chown -R ${JBOSS_USER}: $JBOSS_LOG_DIR

  mkdir -p $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE)
  chown ${JBOSS_USER}: $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE) || true

  if [ ! -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
    start-stop-daemon --start -b -u "$JBOSS_USER" -c "$JBOSS_USER" -d "$JBOSS_HOME" -p "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" -x ${JBOSS_HOME}/"bin/standalone.sh" -- -Djboss.server.log.dir="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"
  else
    log_failure_msg "Error: Environment variable JBOSS_USER not set or empty."
    log_end_msg 1
    exit 1
  fi

  count=0
  launched=false

  until [ $count -gt $STARTUP_WAIT ]
  do
    grep 'JBoss AS.*started in' ${JBOSS_LOG_DIR}"/server.log" > /dev/null 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      launched=true
      break
    fi
    sleep 1
    count=$((count+1));
  done

  if [ $launched=true ]; then
    if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ] && [ -s $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
      log_progress_msg "Successfully started $DESC."
    else
      log_progress_msg "Successfully started $DESC, but problems with pidfile."
    fi
  else
    log_failure_msg "Launching $DESC failed."
    # If the pidfile exists, try to kill the process
    if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ] && [ -s $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
      read kpid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
      log_progress_msg "Pidfile detected. Please take care of process $kpid manually."
    fi
    log_end_msg 1
    exit 1
  fi

  # success
  log_end_msg 0
  return 0
}

stop() {
  log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC"
  count=0;

  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read kpid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    kwait=$SHUTDOWN_WAIT

    # Try issuing SIGTERM

    kill -15 $kpid
    until [ `ps --pid $kpid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $kpid 2> /dev/null` -eq '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
    do
      sleep 1
      count=$((count+1));
    done

    if [ $count -gt $kwait ]; then
      kill -9 $kpid
    fi
  fi
  rm -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE
  log_end_msg 0
  return 0
}

status() {
  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read ppid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
      log_success_msg "$prog is running (pid $ppid)"
      exit 0
    else
      log_success_msg "$prog dead but pid file exists"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
  log_success_msg "$prog is not running"
  exit 3
}

reload() {
  log_begin_msg "Reloading $prog ..."
  start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --chuid jboss --exec ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-cli.sh -- --connect command=:reload
  log_end_msg $?
  exit $?
}

case "$1" in
  start)
      start
      ;;
  stop)
      stop
      ;;
  restart)
      $0 stop
      $0 start
      ;;
  status)
      status
      ;;
  reload)
      reload
      ;;
  *)
      ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|reload}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

And the accompanying configuration (put it in /etc/default/jboss-as ):

```
# JBoss AS configuration
JBOSS_HOME="/var/local/jboss-as"
JBOSS_USER=jboss
```

What works (commands, use `sudo service jboss-as <command>` after linking the script from `/etc/init.d/jboss-as`):

- Startup (blocking until the server started successfully)
- Stopping (also blocking)
- Restart
- Status

What isn't tested:

- If reloading works properly
- What happens if JBoss fails
- What happens for several other possible fails

I didn't dive into several topics yet, especially:

- What does set +e / set -e do exactly and is it required (it's used in other scripts)
- What are the semantics of the log_*_msg functions and where should those be used
- How to properly do the logging stuff (passing the location to JBoss)
- If the jboss-cli.sh script could and should be used for more things (like startup/running detection)
- If it's really necessary to have standalone.sh run as a process all the time
- If the return values are appropriate

Note that I'm definitely no shell script guru - I'm rather quite clueless. So if you find any stupidisms in the code or got any ideas for improvements, I'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.10 the `log_progress_msg` has no output on console. This causes the script not showing up problems (in my case with pid file). Change it to `log_action_msg` and it will give more output

Comment: In order to create pid file the option `--make-pidfile`is needed in the start of the daemon service: start-stop-daemon --start -b -u "$JBOSS_USER" -c "$JBOSS_USER" -d "$JBOSS_HOME" -p "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" --make-pidfile -x ${JBOSS_HOME}/"bin/standalone.sh" -- -Djboss.server.log.dir="$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"

Comment: "What does set +e / set -e do exactly and is it required (it's used in other scripts)"  

This sets the script execution to 'exit on error' mode (so the script isn't continually checking command return codes). You want to keep "-e" so that start errors are caught and not silently ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Recently I wrote installer for JBoss AS 7 that downloads tar.gz file from RedHat's server, extract it, add jboss-as as service and makes some very basic configuration. With it I get ready for use JBoss AS 7 in several seconds.

**Installation script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#title           :jboss-install.sh
#description     :The script to install JBoss AS 7.x
#author          :Dmitriy Sukharev
#date            :20130106
#usage           :/bin/bash jboss-install.sh

JBOSS_AS_FILENAME=jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
JBOSS_AS_ARCHIVE_NAME=$JBOSS_AS_FILENAME.tar.gz 
JBOSS_AS_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS=http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/$JBOSS_AS_FILENAME/$JBOSS_AS_ARCHIVE_NAME

INSTALL_DIR=/opt
JBOSS_AS_FULL_DIR=$INSTALL_DIR/$JBOSS_AS_FILENAME
JBOSS_AS_DIR=$INSTALL_DIR/jboss-as

JBOSS_AS_USER="jboss-as"
JBOSS_AS_SERVICE="jboss-as"

JBOSS_AS_STARTUP_TIMEOUT=240

SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

echo "Cleaning up..."
rm "$JBOSS_AS_ARCHIVE_NAME"
rm "$JBOSS_AS_DIR"
rm -r "$JBOSS_AS_FULL_DIR"
rm -r "/var/run/$JBOSS_AS_SERVICE/"
rm /etc/init.d/$JBOSS_AS_SERVICE

echo "Installation..."
wget $JBOSS_AS_DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS
mkdir $JBOSS_AS_FULL_DIR
tar -xzf $JBOSS_AS_ARCHIVE_NAME -C $INSTALL_DIR
ln -s $JBOSS_AS_FULL_DIR/ $JBOSS_AS_DIR
useradd -s /sbin/nologin $JBOSS_AS_USER
chown -R $JBOSS_AS_USER:$JBOSS_AS_USER $JBOSS_AS_DIR
chown -R $JBOSS_AS_USER:$JBOSS_AS_USER $JBOSS_AS_DIR/
rm $JBOSS_AS_ARCHIVE_NAME

echo "Registrating JBoss as service..."
sed -e 's,${JBOSS_AS_USER},'$JBOSS_AS_USER',g; s,${JBOSS_AS_FILENAME},'$JBOSS_AS_FILENAME',g; s,${JBOSS_AS_SERVICE},'$JBOSS_AS_SERVICE',g; s,${JBOSS_AS_DIR},'$JBOSS_AS_DIR',g' $SCRIPT_DIR/jboss-as.template > /etc/init.d/$JBOSS_AS_SERVICE
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/$JBOSS_AS_SERVICE

echo "Configurating..."
sed -i -e 's,<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>,<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="'$JBOSS_AS_STARTUP_TIMEOUT'"/>,g' $JBOSS_AS_DIR/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
sed -i -e 's,<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">,<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">,g' $JBOSS_AS_DIR/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
sed -i -e 's,<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>,<any-address/>,g' $JBOSS_AS_DIR/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
sed -i -e 's,<socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>,<socket-binding name="ajp" port="28009"/>,g' $JBOSS_AS_DIR/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
sed -i -e 's,<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>,<socket-binding name="http" port="28080"/>,g' $JBOSS_AS_DIR/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
sed -i -e 's,<socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>,<socket-binding name="https" port="28443"/>,g' $JBOSS_AS_DIR/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
sed -i -e 's,<socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>,<socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="28090"/>,g' $JBOSS_AS_DIR/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

echo "Done."
```

**Init script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ${JBOSS_AS_SERVICE}
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/Stop ${JBOSS_AS_FILENAME}
### END INIT INFO

JBOSS_USER=${JBOSS_AS_USER}
JBOSS_DIR=${JBOSS_AS_DIR}

case "$1" in
start)
echo "Starting ${JBOSS_AS_FILENAME}..."
start-stop-daemon --start --background --chuid $JBOSS_USER --exec $JBOSS_DIR/bin/standalone.sh
exit $?
;;
stop)
echo "Stopping ${JBOSS_AS_FILENAME}..."

start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --chuid $JBOSS_USER --exec $JBOSS_DIR/bin/jboss-cli.sh -- --connect command=:shutdown
exit $?
;;
log)
echo "Showing server.log..."
tail -500f $JBOSS_DIR/standalone/log/server.log
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/jboss-as {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

I described the script steps in my [blog post](http://sukharevd.net/jboss-as-7-configuration.html). It also has the link to download this script files as archive.

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/sh

start(){
    echo "Starting JBoss 7"
    sudo -u jboss sh /usr/local/jboss/bin/standalone.sh
}

stop(){
    echo "Stopping JBoss 7"
    sudo -u jboss sh /usr/local/jboss/bin/jboss-admin.sh --connect command=:shutdown
}

restart(){
    stop
    # give stuff some time to stop before we restart
    sleep 60
    # protect against any services that can't stop before we restart 
    su -l jboss -c 'killall java'
    start
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    restart)
        restart
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: jboss {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Watch under **bin** directory you have init.d/jboss-as-standalone.sh (jboss-as-7.1.0.CR1b)

Comment: Those scripts are not compatible with Ubuntu (at least 12.04)

Comment: Anthony O. the user is trying to run scripts in Ubuntu 10.04 not 12.04, and i can't write an answer valid for all future distro :) so don't downvote me, but jboss team

Answer (score 2):

The answer marked as correct here did not work for me. On restart, you get a security error related to the usage of sudo, stating, "sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo." Further research revealed that disabling the sudo tty restriction could cause plain text exposure of passwords, so that's no good.

Here's what I ended up with and it works fine for me:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          jboss
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/Stop JBoss AS v7.0.0
### END INIT INFO
#
#source some script files in order to set and export environmental variables
#as well as add the appropriate executables to $PATH
[ -r /etc/profile.d/java.sh ] && . /etc/profile.d/java.sh
[ -r /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh ] && . /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting JBoss AS 7.0.0"
        su --session-command "${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh >& /dev/null &" jboss
    ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping JBoss AS 7.0.0"
        su --session-command "${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-admin.sh --connect command=:shutdown" jboss
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/jboss {start|stop}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just been fighting through this tonight, and thought I'd share my findings.
In the end i followed the install instructions here: http://ptoconnor.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/jboss-as-7-1-1-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-aws-instance-running-oracle-java-7/
with some alterations;

I installed to /usr/share not /opt

To get jboss to run as a service, i created a symbolic link to the redhat/centos friendly 
/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/init.d/jboss-as-standalone.sh which was provided with the 7.1.1 final release

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/init.d/jboss-as-standalone.sh /etc/init.d/jboss
```

then a few changes to make it ubuntu friendly

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# JBoss standalone control script
#
# chkconfig: - 80 20
# description: JBoss AS Standalone
# processname: standalone
# pidfile: /var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid
# config: /etc/jboss-as/jboss-as.conf

# Source function library.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Load Java configuration.
[ -r /etc/java/java.conf ] && . /etc/java/java.conf
export JAVA_HOME

# Load JBoss AS init.d configuration.
if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONF" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONF="/etc/jboss-as/jboss-as.conf"
fi

[ -r "$JBOSS_CONF" ] && . "${JBOSS_CONF}"

# Set defaults.

if [ -z "$JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
  JBOSS_HOME=/usr/share/jboss-as
fi
export JBOSS_HOME

if [ -z "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" ]; then
  JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/jboss-as/jboss-as-standalone.pid
fi
export JBOSS_PIDFILE

if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG=/var/log/jboss-as/console.log
fi

if [ -z "$STARTUP_WAIT" ]; then
  STARTUP_WAIT=30
fi

if [ -z "$SHUTDOWN_WAIT" ]; then
  SHUTDOWN_WAIT=30
fi

if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONFIG" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONFIG=standalone.xml
fi

JBOSS_SCRIPT=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh

prog='jboss-as'

CMD_PREFIX=''

JBOSS_USER=jboss

if [ ! -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
  if [ -x /lib/lsb/init-functions ]; then
    CMD_PREFIX="start-stop-daemon -user $JBOSS_USER"
  else
    CMD_PREFIX="su - $JBOSS_USER -c"
  fi
fi

start() {
  echo -n "Starting $prog: "
  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read ppid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE;
    if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
      echo -n "$prog is already running"
      failure
      echo
      return 1 
    else
      rm -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    fi
  fi
  mkdir -p $(dirname $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG)
  cat /dev/null > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG

  mkdir -p $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE)
  chown $JBOSS_USER $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE) || true
  #$CMD_PREFIX JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &
  #$CMD_PREFIX JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT &

  if [ ! -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
    if [ -x /lib/lsb/init-functions ]; then
      start-stop-daemon -user $JBOSS_USER LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT -c $JBOSS_CONFIG 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &
    else
      su - $JBOSS_USER -c "LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE $JBOSS_SCRIPT -c $JBOSS_CONFIG" 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &
    fi
  fi

  count=0
  launched=false

  until [ $count -gt $STARTUP_WAIT ]
  do
    grep 'JBoss AS.*started in' $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG > /dev/null 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      launched=true
      break
    fi 
    sleep 1;
    count=`expr $count + 1`
  done

  printf success
  echo
  return 0
}

stop() {
  echo -n "Stopping $prog: "
  count=0;

  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read kpid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE;
    kwait=$SHUTDOWN_WAIT

    # Try issuing SIGTERM

    kill -15 $kpid
    until [ `ps --pid $kpid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $kpid 2> /dev/null` -eq '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
    do
      sleep 1;
      count=`expr $count + 1`
    done

    if [ $count -gt $kwait ]; then
      kill -9 $kpid
    fi
  fi
  rm -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE
  printf success
  echo
}

status() {
  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    read ppid < $JBOSS_PIDFILE
    if [ `ps --pid $ppid 2> /dev/null | grep -c $ppid 2> /dev/null` -eq '1' ]; then
      echo "$prog is running (pid $ppid)"
      return 0
    else
      echo "$prog dead but pid file exists"
      return 1
    fi
  fi
  echo "$prog is not running"
  return 3
}

case "$1" in
  start)
      start
      ;;
  stop)
      stop
      ;;
  restart)
      $0 stop
      $0 start
      ;;
  status)
      status
      ;;
  *)
      ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|reload}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

now it's just a case of installing the jboss service using the above script.

```
sudo update-rc.d jboss defaults
```

I know there are lots of variations now, but hopefully this will help the next person searching. All i wanted was a JBPM host ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine for gentoo.  Not perfect yet but pretty clean and working well enough for me.   First one small change to the jboss install:

```
~ # JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss   # or whatever you have it as
~ # echo "LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=true"  >> "${JBOSS_HOME}"/bin/standalone.conf
```

.

```
~ # cat /etc/conf.d/jboss
JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss
JBOSS_USER=jboss
JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/jboss/jboss.pid
JBOSS_EXECUTABLE="${JBOSS_HOME}"/bin/standalone.sh
JBOSS_STDOUT_LOG=/var/log/jboss/stdout.log
JBOSS_STDERR_LOG=/var/log/jboss/stderr.log
JBOSS_SHUTDOWN_WAIT_SECONDS=60
```

.

```
~ # cat /etc/init.d/jboss
#!/sbin/runscript

depend()  {
        need net
}

start() {
        ebegin "Starting JBoss"
        start-stop-daemon -S -b -m -p "${JBOSS_PIDFILE}" -u "${JBOSS_USER}" -x "${JBOSS_EXECUTABLE}" -1 "${JBOSS_STDOUT_LOG}" -2 "${JBOSS_STDERR_LOG}"
        eend $?
} 

stop() {
        ebegin "Stopping JBoss"
        start-stop-daemon -K -p "${JBOSS_PIDFILE}" -u "${JBOSS_USER}" -R ${JBOSS_SHUTDOWN_WAIT_SECONDS}
        eend $?
}
```

I can't get startup to say [ OK ] as soon as the deployments all finish.  I've tried a few things but no luck yet - it either waits forever or currently just says [ OK ] as soon as the shell script is forked.  Stopping is better, as long as you set the delay long enough. Log rotation would be pretty easy to add

Answer (score 0):

There is a directory in the jboss distribution located in bin/init.d with a shell script you can place in init.d to launch jboss as a service. The script is called jboss-as-standalone.sh

Comment: It doesn't work very well on Ubuntu. Startup scrips are very distro-dependent.

Comment: Those scripts are not compatible with Ubuntu (at least 12.04)

Answer (score 0):

I found no solution here which were really working... (at least for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

So I made my own one (which is able to start JBoss & wait for it to complete, and stop it, using the `start-stop-daemon` utils) :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# JBoss standalone control script
#
# Based on the file provided in JBoss AS 7.1.1 (https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/blob/master/build/src/main/resources/bin/init.d/jboss-as-standalone.sh)
# inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880902/start-jboss-7-as-a-service-on-linux and http://ptoconnor.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/jboss-as-7-1-1-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-aws-instance-running-oracle-java-7/
# Modified for Ubuntu Server 12.04 by Anthony O.
#
# chkconfig: - 80 20
# description: JBoss AS Standalone
# config: /etc/default/jboss-as-7
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          jboss-as
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Should-Start:      $named
# Should-Stop:       $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start JBoss AS
# Description:       Start JBoss Application Server.
### END INIT INFO
#

JBOSS_CONF="/opt/jboss-as-7/bin/init.d/jboss-as.conf"

NAME=jboss-as-7
DEFAULT=/etc/default/$NAME

# Source function library.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Load Java configuration.
# Ubuntu has it in /etc/default
[ -r /etc/default/java ] && . /etc/default/java
export JAVA_HOME

# Load JBoss AS init.d configuration.
if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONF" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONF=$DEFAULT
fi

[ -r "$JBOSS_CONF" ] && . "${JBOSS_CONF}"

# Set defaults.

if [ -z "$JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
  JBOSS_HOME="/var/local/$NAME"
fi
export JBOSS_HOME

if [ -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
  JBOSS_USER="jboss"
fi
export JBOSS_USER

if [ -z "$JBOSS_PIDFILE" ]; then
  JBOSS_PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME/jboss-as-standalone.pid
fi
export JBOSS_PIDFILE

if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG=/var/log/$NAME/console.log
fi

# We need this to be set to get a pidfile !
if [ -z "$LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND" ]; then
  LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=true
fi
export LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND

if [ -z "$STARTUP_WAIT" ]; then
  STARTUP_WAIT=120
fi

if [ -z "$SHUTDOWN_WAIT" ]; then
  SHUTDOWN_WAIT=120
fi

if [ -z "$JBOSS_CONFIG" ]; then
  JBOSS_CONFIG=standalone.xml
fi

JBOSS_SCRIPT=$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh

MATCHING_ARGS=(--user "$JBOSS_USER" --pidfile "$JBOSS_PIDFILE")

start() {
  log_daemon_msg "Starting $NAME"
  id $JBOSS_USER > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ $? -ne 0 -o -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
    log_failure_msg "User $JBOSS_USER does not exist..."
    log_end_msg 1
    exit 1
  fi

  mkdir -p $(dirname $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG)
  cat /dev/null > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG
  chown $JBOSS_USER $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG

  mkdir -p $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE)
  chown ${JBOSS_USER}: $(dirname $JBOSS_PIDFILE) || true

  if [ ! -z "$JBOSS_USER" ]; then
    start-stop-daemon --start ${MATCHING_ARGS[@]} --oknodo --chuid "$JBOSS_USER" --chdir "$JBOSS_HOME" --retry $STARTUP_WAIT $(if [ "$LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND" == "true" ] ; then echo "--background" ; fi) --startas /bin/bash -- -c "exec $JBOSS_SCRIPT -c $JBOSS_CONFIG 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG"
  else
    log_failure_msg "Error: Environment variable JBOSS_USER not set or empty."
    log_end_msg 1
    exit 1
  fi

  if [ "$LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND" == "true" ] ; then
    count=0
    launched_status=1

    until [ $count -gt $STARTUP_WAIT ]
    do
      grep 'JBAS015874:' $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG > /dev/null 
      if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        launched_status=0
        break
      fi 
      sleep 1
      let count=$count+1;
    done

    log_end_msg $launched_status
    return $launched_status
  else
    log_end_msg $?
    return $?
  fi
}

stop() {
  log_daemon_msg "Stopping $NAME"

  END_STATUS=0
  if [ -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE ]; then
    start-stop-daemon --stop ${MATCHING_ARGS[@]} --retry $SHUTDOWN_WAIT
    END_STATUS=$?
    rm -f $JBOSS_PIDFILE
  fi
  log_end_msg $END_STATUS
  return $END_STATUS
}

status() {
  start-stop-daemon --status --verbose ${MATCHING_ARGS[@]}
  exit $?
}

reload() {
  log_begin_msg "Reloading $prog ..."
  start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid ${JBOSS_USER} --exec ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-cli.sh -- --connect command=:reload
  log_end_msg $?
  exit $?
}

case "$1" in
  start)
      start
      ;;
  stop)
      stop
      ;;
  restart)
      $0 stop
      $0 start
      ;;
  status)
      status
      ;;
  reload)
      reload
      ;;
  *)
      ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|reload}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

One can change the `JBOSS_CONF` variable near the top of the file as well as removing it if the `jboss-as.conf` file is located at `/etc/default/jboss-as-7`.

Answer (score 0):

To print PID of command executed use shell variable $!. This variable will print PID of process executed.

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting JBoss AS 7.0.0"
        su --session-command "${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh >& /dev/null &" jboss
        echo $! > /tmp/jboss.pid
    ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run JBoss as a service on linux:

[JBoss as service in linux](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToInstallJBossAS7AsALinuxService)