# JBoss AS 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 server - Deployment errors

Tags: deployment, war, jboss7.x, ubuntu-server

### **Setup**

I setup a virtual machine with Ubuntu 12.04 64bit where I want
to run JBoss AS 7 and deploy Nexus OSS as a war file.

[This tutorial](http://alexander.holbreich.org/2011/11/jboss-7-setup-linux/) was used to setup JBoss as a service on linux.
I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880902/start-jboss-7-as-a-service-on-linux), too, but the configuration script configuration
didn't worked for as well as the script shipped with JBoss in `bin/init.d/`.

### **Deployment Problem**

No I'm trying to deploy the [Nexus OSS war file](http://www.sonatype.org/downloads/nexus-2.0.6.war). I had two different approaches.

**1. Deploy it via the webinterfaces**

I got this error

```
Request
{
  "address" => [("deployment" => "nexus")],
  "operation" => "deploy"
}
Response
Internal Server Error
{
 "outcome" => "failed",
 "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>{"jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/nexus-2.0.6\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host.\"/nexus-2.0.6\": JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}},
 "rolled-back" => true
}
```

**2. Autodeploy it in /usr/local/jboss-as-7/standalone/deployments/**

```
JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds].
Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.
```

However I could find any logs. I search in

```
/var/log/jboss
$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the most recent WAR, but I tried deploying the Nexus WAR on JBoss AS 7, GlassFish, Geronimo and TomEE without success. They all had different errors. From what I was gathering that WAR just won't work on any Java EE application server. I was only able to get it to work on a servlet container like Tomcat or jetty.

Comment: So you think this is a problem related to the Nexus OSS WAR file and has nothing to do with the JBoss Installation?

Comment: Correct. I can't remember which 2.x version I tried, but I had an issue with every Java EE server I tried.