# start oracle weblogic server when system starts

Tags: oracle10g, ubuntu-14.04, weblogic-10.x

I want to set Oracle weblogic server 10.3.6 to start automatically when my Ubuntu machine starts.
At this moment, I start it from this sh file manually

Oracle > MiddleWare > user_domains > base_domain > bin > startWebLogic.sh

Comment: Found a solution at
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to start a process like this... you can use `cron` or you can use a service in `/etc/init.d` ... not sure which one you are looking for.

For a super simple `/etc/init.d` example:

- Create `/etc/init.d/weblogic_start`

  - Add the following:
    `su – user -c "/path/to/script/startWebLogic.sh &"`

This will start Weblogic every time the machine boots. See other questions like: [Start JBoss 7 as a service on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880902/start-jboss-7-as-a-service-on-linux)

Comment: how to do it with 'cron' ?